# Three.js Curve Path Animation

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am Developing a webgl based game using three.js, however I couldn't find anything regarding curve path animation. What I want is to create obstacles in my game which comes in the path of the actor and he has to dodge the obstacles that is coming. I want this obstacle to follow and repeat the curve path motion, like a sphere following this curve path.

How do I create such animation ?

Answer (score 7):

http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_splines
See this example and how the camera is made to follow the spline path. I think this is quite the thing you are looking for, just for a sphere instead of the camera.